# Add a news subscriber using observer pattern with events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, console, observer-pattern

I am using the observer pattern to add and remove subscribers from a newsletter using events.

I'm not sure how to approach what I'm trying to do. Is it possible to add a subscriber using an event and how?

The console is operated by a form with buttons so when the button is clicked it will add subscribers and when the remove button is clicked it will remove a subscriber, on the form, there is also a button to post a newsletter which will post a newsletter for each subscriber.

This is what I have managed to get so far:

```
class Program
{
    //[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SoftwareRevolution softrev = new Ass_3._1.SoftwareRevolution();
        ConsoleOutput First = new ConsoleOutput(softrev);
        softrev.Datetime = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
        Application.Run(new InputForm());            
    }
}

public delegate void NotifyMe(string Value);

class ConsoleOutput : IEventsObserver
{
    IEventsSubject IEventsSubject;
    public ConsoleOutput(IEventsSubject IEventsSubject)
    {
        this.IEventsSubject = IEventsSubject;
        this.IEventsSubject.Notifier += new Ass_3._1.NotifyMe(UpdateNews);
    }

    public void UpdateNews(string info)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(info);
    }
}

interface IEventsObserver
{
    void UpdateNews(string info);
}

interface IEventsSubject
{
    event NotifyMe Notifier;
}

class SoftwareRevolution : IEventsSubject
{
    List<IEventsObserver> Readers = new List<IEventsObserver>();
    private string datetime;
    public string Datetime
    {
        get
        {
            return datetime;
        }

        set
        {
            datetime = value;
            Notifier(datetime);
        }
    }

    public event NotifyMe Notifier;        
}
```

Comment: The object which issues a newsletter, should have an event which fires when a newsletter issues. Then all subscribes which has subscribed for that event will receive it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you, but what I'm trying to do is add subscribers to a list of subscribers through events

Comment: have you tried to use observable collection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Subscription management is different than distributing newsletter. The publisher just knows about publishing and raises an event about a new newsletter. The subscriber manager helps the subscribers to subscribe for that event. Usually the publisher doesn't need to keep list of subscribers itself. (Distribution of event will be done without having such list. The event implementation in C# takes care of that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object which issues a newsletter, should have an event which fires when a newsletter issues. Then all subscribes which has subscribed for that event will receive it.

Distribution of event will be done without having such list in publisher class. In fact the delegate implementation in C# takes care of that and there is an invokation list behind the event delegate.

Usually the *Publisher* doesn't need to keep list of *Subscriber* object itself and if you need such list, it's better to keep it in a *SubscriptionManager*.

The subscription manager, subscribes and unsubscribes the subscribers to the event of publisher. It also can keep a list of subscribers.

**Example**

The `Newsletter` class contains some fields which represents a newsletter:

```
public class Newsletter
{
    public string Content;
}
```

The `NewsLetterPublishedEventArgs` contains information about published newsletter:

```
public class NewsletterPublishedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Newsletter Newsletter { get; set; }
}
```

The `Publisher` class published the newsletter and raises an event after publishing:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler<NewsletterPublishedEventArgs> NewsLetterPublished;
    public void PublishNewsLetter()
    {
        var newsLetter = new Newsletter() { Content = $"New publish at {DateTime.Now}" };
        NewsLetterPublished?.Invoke(this, 
            new NewsletterPublishedEventArgs() { Newsletter = newsLetter });
    }
}
```

The `Subscriber` class has a method which allows it to receive `NewsLetterPublished` notification:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void ReceiveNewsLetter(object sender, NewsletterPublishedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Newsletter.Content);
    }
}
```

At the end, `SubscriptionManager` class subscribes and unsubscribes subscribers to the publisher:

```
public class SubscriptionManager
{
    public Publisher Publisher => new Publisher();
    private List<Subscriber> subscribers;
    public void Subscribe(Subscriber s)
    {
        if (!subscribers.Contains(s))
        {
            subscribers.Add(s);
            Publisher.NewsLetterPublished += s.ReceiveNewsLetter;
        }
    }
    public void Unsubscribe(Subscriber s)
    {
        if (subscribers.Contains(s))
        {
            subscribers.Remove(s);
            Publisher.NewsLetterPublished -= s.ReceiveNewsLetter;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

To keep thing simple I created a simple example to just demonstrate the logic for learning purpose. In a real world example, you need to use interfaces, generic classes and dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped after interpreting it into my scenario.